# start from main activity when resume from recent apps (after startActivityForResult)

Tags: android

I'm launching the camera app with startActivityForResult.
When the app resume from the recent apps, I want it to start from the main/root activity.

I tried to use the intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY but then the resultCode of the camera activity is always RESULT_CANCELED (even when the user clicks ""OK").

```
captureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_CODE);
```

On the manifest I tried to use the android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" but it resume to the camera activity when launch from the recent apps (and not to the main activity as I want it to):

```
<activity
        android:name="com.myApp.Main"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" 
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>    
 </activity>
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Do all these things to the second activity means captureIntent Activty. And Launch mainActivity normally means don't set these flags to "com.myApp.Main" activity

Comment: I use the android camera , it does not appear in my AndroidManifest.xml.